# Tracing variables in Lua for read access to start user defined C++ method/function

Tags: c++, callback, lua

I'm in the process of evaluating script language interpreters to be embedded in C++ applications. TCL/cpptcl and Lua are in my focus right now. TCL has a nice feature that enables me to "trace variable accesses". So whenever I read a defined variable, my read-callback function is triggered:

```
int read_trace(const int& v, void *) {
  cout << "read trace triggered" << endl;
  return v;
}
...
void tclInterpreter() {
  std::cout << ": Starting TCL interpreter!" << std::endl;

  // new TCL
  Tcl::interpreter i;

  i.def_read_trace("tracedVar", "read", read_trace);

  // load the script
  ifstream script("helloworld.tcl");

  // run the script with the given arguments
  i.eval(script);
}
```

So if I now execute the following TCL from my C++ application:

```
set tracedVar 10
for { set i 0 } { $i <= 5 } { incr i } {
  puts $tracedVar
}
```

I receive the output:

```
read trace triggered
10
read trace triggered
10
read trace triggered
10
read trace triggered
10
read trace triggered
10
read trace triggered
10
```

So I get execution of my variable read callback and then the puts-value of the var.

QUESTION: Can I do this with Lua and if yes how? I did not find any direct topic on this. Only thing that caught my eye was about debugging Lua, where a debugger (debugging API) would watch the value of a variable. But I do not want to watch for value changes, but for value access.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't confuse between [Lua](https://github.com/LuaDist/lua) and [LUA](https://github.com/mniip/lua). Both languages are different. "Lua" is a name, and means "Moon" in Portugese. Please **do not write** it as _"LUA"_, which is both ugly and confusing, because then it becomes an acronym with [different meanings](http://acronyms.thefreedictionary.com/lua) for different people.

Answer (score 1):

I think the closest thing to this in lua is an `__index` [metamethod](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#2.8) on a table (with a check for the specific key if you only want to trigger on one).

This could even be done on the default global table (`_G`) if desired.

Comment: This is the first time I got involved with Lua, so excuse me, if this might not be obvious to me.
This indeed looks interesting for tables. I found a small tutorial on how this works on tables ([link](http://nova-fusion.com/2011/06/30/lua-metatables-tutorial)). Reading through this I get an idea how I could call arbitrary functions on access on tables.

I cannot enforce the use of tables if a simple variable should do the job. What about ...

  myVar = 6
  print(myVar)

myVar is not a table. print is accessing the value of myVar. So on print(myVar) a user defined function needs to be called.

Comment: The default global table (what you assign to and retrieve from for global variables) is a table (exposed as `_G` by the reference interpreter). As such you can use an `__index` metamethod on that too. That being said you cannot do this for local variables and you cannot do this without a proxy (and the `__newindex` metamethod) if you need to allow assignment without breaking the `__index` metamethod being called.